# How do I equip an item to my main hand without opening my inventory?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've seen it done on youtube, even in my own servers, where someone has an empty slot in their hot bar, and they press a key bind and like magic, the same item being used gets popped into the hot bar again. I would like to be able to finish using a stack of stone or something, and then just press a button and fill that hot bar slot again with another stack of stone. I can't find the answer anywhere and it would make my large projects take much less time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same item again, it's the block they're looking at. If you for example have dirt somewhere in your inventory and press the "pick block" key (default is middle click) while looking at dirt, your currently selected item (preferably nothing) will be swapped with dirt.

Comment: Let's add the 'pick block is by default bound to middle mouse button.

Comment: Done. I didn't remember anymore which one it was, because my keybinds are almost all changed. :)

Comment: For creative mode: holding Ctrl and then pressing the middle button also copies NBT data of that block, it will give you a chest containing the same items as the chest you are looking at, it will give you a command block with the same command inside, as the one you look at, or it will give you a sign with the same text written on it, as the one you are looking at, or etc. You can also use the middle click to get a spawn egg of whatever mob you look at (and i believe you can also copy the NBT-data by holding Ctrl while doing so, but I'm not sure about that.)

Answer (score -2):

Mods, unless you're talking about from the off-hand to the main-hand, which is [F] by default, but from the way you worded your question, the answer is game mods (or server plugins).

Comment: While it's understandable to get frustrated over what you see as a lack of research, I'm afraid that doesn't have any bearing to your answer.  Please try to focus on the answer itself.

Comment: @Frank I was trying to help. For future reference, advice to new users goes as a comment to the question?

Comment: Nothing wrong with trying to help, Alexander.  Just that telling users to research doesn't belong in an answer.  You can try it with a comment, but it'll be hard to convey a friendly tone when telling someone their question isn't up to spec.  Better usually to just stick to downvotes.